# add ssl certificate to spring boot application and deploy it in jboss

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, jboss7.x

I am trying to add ssl certificate to spring boot application adding ssl configuration in the application.properties file. It is working if I am running it in eclipse but I want to deploy it in JBoss server, JBoss server is not reading ssl configuration from an application properties file

Comment: try setting these properties in System.setProperty();

Comment: i have tried to implement this article https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath but not complete stape 5(how to write class loader and where i have to write )so this class can read property form system.properties file